# What is the best way to generate all binary strings of the given length in Python using Recursion?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary

I'm now studying recursion and try to build some codes to generate all binary strings of the given length 'n'.
I found a code to use for loop:

```
n = 5
for i in range(2**n, 2**(n+1)):
    print(bin(i)[3:])
```

But is there any other way to solve this problem using recursion?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output?

Comment: if input = 2
the output should be 00, 01, 10, 11

Comment: Although the question is valid, but if put specific constraint (`recursion`, here) on then we miss on *pythonic* ways to solve the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to determine what way is "the best" ;)

We have to add zero or one to current string and go to the next recursion level.

Stop-condition is reaching of needed length (here `n-1` because we have to provide leading one corresponding to your example)

```
def genbin(n, bs = ''):
    if n-1:
        genbin(n-1, bs + '0')
        genbin(n-1, bs + '1')
    else:
        print('1' + bs)

genbin(4)

1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Comment: This solution is missing half the output strings, those starting with `0`!

Comment: @joanis Have you seen author code with range 2**n, 2**(n+1)? This assumes no leading zeros, that is why I add '1' in else branch (leading digit)

Comment: OP contradicts that, possibly their own question, in the comments under the question, then, because they say "if input = 2 the output should be 00, 01, 10, 11". The question should be edited to roll that comment into the question.

Comment: @joanis There is no problem to make code for generation of sequences with leading zeros, but I did answer to asked question.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. The code they show and the comment do indeed contradict each other. You read the question more carefully than I did!

Comment: I take it back. I fixed the typo in OP's code to use `bin(i)` instead of `bin[i]`, and then noticed they used `[3:]` to strip out the first digit. They range from 2**n to 2**(n+1) and strip out the 1, so that with n=4, the output is indeed 0000 .. 1111, and not just 1000 .. 1111.

Answer (score 4):

Answer given by MBo is not giving correct answer for input 2 and 3.

eg.
Input: 2

Output should be:

> 0 0
>
> 0 1
>
> 1 0
>
> 1 1

Input: 3

Output should be:

> 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 1
>
> 0 1 0
>
> 0 1 1
>
> 1 0 0
>
> 1 0 1
>
> 1 1 0
>
> 1 1 1

I have modified same code as follows

```
def genbin(n, bs=''):
if len(bs) == n:
    print(bs)
else:
    genbin(n, bs + '0')
    genbin(n, bs + '1')


genbin(3)


000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Harish and generate a list of strings

```
def generate_binary_strings(bit_count):
    binary_strings = []
    def genbin(n, bs=''):
        if len(bs) == n:
            binary_strings.append(bs)
        else:
            genbin(n, bs + '0')
            genbin(n, bs + '1')


    genbin(bit_count)
    return binary_strings

binary_strings = generate_binary_strings(6)
print(binary_strings)
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution shown in all the answers, according to my timings I just ran.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getbin(n, s=['']):
    if n > 0:
        return [
            *getbin(n - 1, [i + '0' for i in s]),
            *getbin(n - 1, [j + '1' for j in s])
        ]
    return s
```

Comment: This works, but have you verified if this is any faster or better than the other solutions. You're going to make  a lot more copies of the partial lists in memory, I'd be interested in comparing performance.

Comment: Good point. I quickly compared runtimes and it is clearly slower than lode's solution

Comment: Yeah, I just did some comparisons, and lode's is fastest, and yours about 2x slower in my timings.

Comment: I thought I'd share this approach anyway (also, OP didn't put any emphasis on small runtime).

Comment: Yes, it's a bit slower, but it's good to see different approaches to the same problem. Thanks for your answer.